# If I am voting on an answer, and that user has hit the daily limit, what happens?

Tags: support, voting

if the user I am voting on (upvote) has hit the daily maximum, does my vote get rejected? i.e. the vote will not increment?

Comment: Go to StackOverflow, upvote Jon Skeet, and find out.

Answer (score 7):

The vote is incremented, but no reputation is gained. So you can still see how many people actually like an answer, but it just doesn't help the poster's reputation.

Comment: ok so reputation (points) can't be gained, but badges can?  Doesn't that basically mean that you can manipulate badges but not points?

Comment: Yes, badges can be gained. I'm not sure how you'd "manipulate" badges though - the rep cap is to stop people from gaining a lot of rep (and thus power) really quickly, rather than to stop people from gaming the rep system (IMO, anyway).

Comment: (Indeed, if badges *couldn't* be gained and votes weren't counted, it would greatly disfavour those who post a lot of answers. I suspect I'd be stuck on very few badges...)

Comment: pfff, 1200 badges is nothing...  :)

Comment: I hope you don't get any rep from my upvote, Jon.